# How do I find the highest daily/monthly/yearly scores ever using the Data Explorer?

Tags: support

I've tried looking for it at the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=users+daily+score), but can't seem to find a link and don't know the syntax.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: This one is [fairly easy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: @MartinSmith Went through the whole page. :(

Comment: If there was only one page you just looked at the featured ones. Though I've just discovered the search function there and don't see anything promising in the others.

Comment: @MartinSmith Should have mentioned I found [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/946/rising-stars-top-50-users-ordered-on-rep-per-day) but that query is invalid now.

Comment: I think the record daily total is 1550 for David Robinson on Jul 6 '13 - he got 3*500 bounties on that day. A not very accurate query you can extend is http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/691558/meta-351684 (doesn't take into account rep from editing, documentation, deleted users and posts and maybe other things)

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh, that's a start. How do I modify it for month or year?

Comment: Step 1. Learn SQL

Comment: @MartinSmith Lol. Was waiting for someone to say that to me in this post.

Comment: I'm just wondering... how did you find this query with a cryptic name like META 351684?

Comment: I wrote the query. 351684 is the QuestionId of this post

Comment: Oh... saw a different username, threw me off. Thank you for that. :)